# Grep records from Excel or txt file with certain area codes

Tags: grep

I know how to pull certain records in a text file by using something like below code when I want all records that have year date of 2018. Below is a sample record I am dealing with and now I need the code to extract just the certain area codes from the list of thousands of 10 digit phone numbers in file. I actually have to pull several area codes, so if can do all at once, that would be great. Here is code I used for year:

```
grep 2018-01 mca159.182.txt
```

Although above works, it doesn't extract those records to a file, even if I put -o and the file name I want it to create and put the records in. It still just displays all results that have 2018 in terminal, where I have no choice but to copy and paste. So that tip would be helpful too, in order for me to have results put into a new text file.  Here is what the file format I am dealing with looks like:

```
phone       dob     size
9546022996  8/7/17  199000
9123842128  8/7/17  199000
```

So say I wanted to extract all 10 digit phone numbers or actually the whole record is what I want, meaning the three columns would be exported to a new file or on screen at least, for all numbers that start with 954, 213, 909. So if worked, then it would find the first record above as match.

Comment: Mike, somehow I've modified the question. I think better you refer the link https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask. Actually this query belongs to UNIX therefore I've included a new tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions here:

1) How to send the output from grep to a file, not to the terminal screen?

The -o option for grep just shows the matching portion of any line.  You're perhaps thinking of sort -o with this question?

```
grep 2018-01 mca159.182.txt > newfile.txt
```

Will send any matching lines to newfile.txt.

2) How to use grep to match the first three characters in a file, for multiple possible possible matches?

```
grep -E "^954|^213|^909" mca159.182.txt > newfile.txt
```

We have to specify extended regular expressions with -E (or use the command egrep) to be able to use the | symbol (called the alternation operator in the grep manual).  The "^" character is an anchor and means just match where the three characters are at the start of the line.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, I put this in my terminal and it did create the file

Comment: grep -E "^213|^215|^213|^570|^610|^215|^302|^609|^856|^732|^717|^848" dentest.txt > dentestdone.txt

Comment: it created the dentestdone.txt but no contents and I know that one 215 area code was in the dentest.txt so not sure why the dentestdone.txt is empty? and no error on terminal. Let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try it with a small snippet of the file - grab the first 10 lines with "head -10 dentest.txt > den10.txt" and try it with that.  What O/S or version of grep are you using?

Comment: Here is what response was and my exact code used: Not sure what this response means? Maybe it didn't find a match in top10 rows?

Comment: iMacs-iMac-2:curl user$ grep -E ^213|^215|^213|^570|^610|^215|^302|^609|^856|^732|^717|^848 head -10 dentest.txt > den10.txt
-bash: ^215: command not found
-bash: ^213: command not found
-bash: ^570: command not found
-bash: ^610: command not found
-bash: ^215: command not found
-bash: ^302: command not found
-bash: ^609: command not found
-bash: ^856: command not found
-bash: ^732: command not found
-bash: ^717: command not found
-bash: ^848: command not found

Comment: You need quotes around the search pattern, otherwise bash is grabbing the | character and thinks you're trying to pipe to another command.  And you can't have the "head -10" part in the middle like that.  Try this: 1) grep -E "^213" dentest.txt > den.txt ; then 2) head -10 den.txt; then 3) grep -E "^213|^215" dentest.txt > den.txt.  That should make sense, right?

Comment: hmm, I tried all that and file gets created of den.txt but no contents no matter which way i do it above. In original file of dentest.txt it has 10 digit phone #"s in column A and other stuff in B and C, so do I need to tell where it is or why is it not exporting the found records with 213 or 215 in the new file? This code creates the file I used: grep -E "^213|^215" dentest.txt > den1.txt